# calling Javascript at page load

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript

I have a Javascript.  I want to call only at page load. I dont want to call at postbacks.. (Asp.net 3,5)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell, javascript in MasterPage. So jscript is fired at every page load..

Comment: I couldnt solve this problem. When content page is loading Jscript is running. I dont want to do this. I want to call Jscript only one (1) time..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", "someFunction();", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want the script to run only once you could use a `Session` property which indicates whether the script has run and based on its value include or not the script.

Comment: Ok. I think it is impossible to run once at initialization of the masterpage life cycle.

Comment: How can I set value to Session? Because every page load Session value will be reset? I cant check session value and call javascript..

Answer (score 1):

Try out the Page.IsPostback property
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Comment: You might want to combine this with the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript technique  so that the script is only added inside if (!Page.IsPostBack) {}

Answer (score 0):

Better thing is to call your java script function at the  tag on load. Here the java script calls only once.not in all post backs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach to the load event to avoid accidentally overriding the onload in the body tag with document.onload in JavaScript.  This is usually only a problem with master pages having content pages implement their own load event and overriding the master page JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Page_loaded() {
        //Do Work
    }

    if (document.all) {
        //IE
        window.attachEvent('onload', Page_loaded);
    } else {
        //Everything else
        window.addEventListener('load', Page_loaded, false);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body onload="javascript:yourFunctionCall()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will still run on postback

Comment: This will be called in Postback.

Comment: This way you do not eat computer time to add strings, code etc.